# PHP Foreach loop with a single array to MySQL from XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, foreach

I start from xml file with following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<severa>
<mesaj id="6caca93f" tip="ATENTIONARE"cod="GALBEN"" />
<mesaj id="6caca93g" tip="ATENTIONARE" cod="GALBEN"  />
</severa>
```

Using PHP with xml2Array function I obtain below array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[id] => 6caca93f
[tip] => ATENTIONARE
[cod] => GALBEN
)
)
[1] => Array
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[id] => 6caca93g
[tip] => ATENTIONARE
[cod] => GALBEN
)
)
)
```

I read this result with foreach and insert this 2 records into MySql.
Now the problem: this works only for multiple records in xml (>2). If I have only one record in xml the array look like below and no row is inserted. Could you please advice what I should do?

Seems that this array with a single entry have a different form. I hope this is not the reason
Thank you so much!

```
    Array
(
[@attributes] => Array
(
[id] => 6caca93f
[tip] => ATENTIONARE
[cod] => GALBEN
)
)
```

Foreach is like this:

```
foreach ($a as $row) {
        $atributes = $row['@attributes'];
        $id = $atributes['id'];
        $tip = $atributes['tip'];
        $cod = $atributes['cod'];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
    }
```

Comment: "with xml2Array function" _what_ xml2Array function?  There is no native PHP `xml2Array()` function.

Comment: It is not native, yes. But can be added in order to convert xml to phph array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xml2Array` function is treating a single record differently from a list of records, adding an extra dimension in the second case. You need to treat the first case specially.

```
if (isset($a['@attributes'])) { // Single record, turn it into an array
    $a = array($a);
}
```

Then your loop will work for both cases.